# Kafka got error Exception (BufferUnderflowException)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

guys:

I want to connect Kafka with nodejs. Version Kafka is **0.8.2** and the module of nodejs is **kafka**(Version **0.2.3**) .

My Kafka server is in my virsualbox 192.168.1.104(with default setting,nothing change)

Here is the node code(run it in 192.168.1.1), it's very simple:

```
var kafka = require('kafka')
new kafka.Consumer().connect().subscribeTopic('test').on('message',     function(topic, message) {
 console.log("Consumed message:", message)
})

var producer = new kafka.Producer({
    host:         '192.168.1.104',
    port:         9092,
    topic:        'test',
    partition:    0
}).connect().on('connect', function() {
    producer.send("hey!")
    producer.close()
});
```

After run this code : In server side ,they caught an error Exception:

```
2015-09-26 20:15:56,494] ERROR Closing socket for /192.168.1.102 because of  error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:361)
at kafka.api.FetchRequest$.readFrom(FetchRequest.scala:47)
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$2.apply(RequestKeys.scala:40)
at kafka.api.RequestKeys$$anonfun$2.apply(RequestKeys.scala:40)
at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:50)
at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:450)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure if i should make some change to handle it.or did i miss something .Hope someone will Help me out,thanks!

Comment: What kafka library (node library) is this?  Is the error caused by the consumer code or the producer code?

Comment: Do you have zookeeper running?

Comment: @sberry yes ,the zookeeper running very well . bug in running log there are some errors  ` 
[2015-09-26 21:50:20,655] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1500d2312480000 type:delete cxid:0x27 zxid:0x2ae txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
`

Comment: @sberry kafka library is [kafka](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka) ,both the producer and  consumer code will got error in server side , no messages will be appended

Answer (score 2):

Question Sloved!

That problem caused by misconfigged : the Kafka server must be setting like:

in server.properties file:

> advertised.host.name=192.168.1.104

default is localhost : so the client can't routed to destination,you must set a real ipaddress so the remote client can talk with server!